# Image generation using autoencoder vs. variational autoencoder

Tags: autoencoder, image-generation

When we use the convolutional autoencoder for new image  generating,
does the model generate the same image every time we run the model? or does it rather generate images  with random variation?
I think that the autoencoder (AE) generates the same new images every time we run the model because it maps the input image to a single point in the latent space. On the other hand, the variational autoencoder (VAE) maps the the input image to a distribution. Therefore, if we need images with some random variation we need to use VAE and if we need the same generated images every time we run the model we use AE. Is this true?
My question is:
Does AE generate images with random variation?

Answer (score 1):

Autoencoders first encode the input data into some latent representation and then use that representation (bottleneck layer) to reconstruct the same input.
I trained an autoencoder on MNIST data and encoded the digits into a two-dimensional vector. The network learned quite a useful representation of the data that I plotted.
[Latent representation of MNIST digit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5fqv.png)

You can see for each digit the latent representation has some range of values for example zero's latent representation has nearly range from -2 to 4 on the x-axis and 4 to 8 on the y axis.
Now if you sample a random two-dimensional random vector in that range and run it through a decoder, you will get a random image of zero.
Now the problem is this is a very simple case. How about latent vector has 64 dimensions or even higher and a number of categories are also more. In that case, we need to model the distribution of the latent vector in order to sample valid vectors. Otherwise, we would never know that which latent vector is valid.
So autoencoder may give random samples, but it needs to know the distribution of data and that point we cover in VAE.